# Yii Relation Has_Many Filtering

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I currently have 2 db tables, one containing a list of shows and one containing times these shows are on.

So I have a HAS_MANY relationship between the two.

I have successfully managed to pull out the films and the times associated to them via the HAS_MANY relationship.

The section I am struggling with is I want to show the first 10 films that have times against them (some do not). The code below pulls out just the first 10 irrelevant of whether they have times against them:

```
$films=filmrecord::model()
     ->findAll(array(
         'order' => 'priority',
         'limit' => 10
     ));

foreach ($films as $thefilm) {
        array_push($filmListings, array(
            'id' => $thefilm->id,
            'title' => $thefilm->title,
            'url' => $thefilm->url,
            'poster_url' => $thefilm->p_url,
            'times' => $thefilm->filmtimes
        ));
 }

return filmListings;
```

The HAS_MANY relationship I am using is:

```
 'filmtimes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FilmsTimesRecord', 'film_id')
```

I know I could simply put in a if statement to check if $thefilm->filmtimes was set however ideally I would like to check at an db point to avoid having to pull all films out before checking.

Is there any way I can the existence of a relationship within the findAll?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Regards
wizzer

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution for find all film with film times records using `has_many` relationship.

```
'filmtimes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FilmsTimesRecord', 'film_id')

$films=filmrecord::model()->with('filmtimes')->findAll(array('order' => 'priority','limit' => 10));
```